# Ionic2 Scroll List in Header

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic2

I am using Ionic2, and I am trying to create a header with a list of 5 scrollable items. There is an infinite list of other items under the header.

I would like this header list to collapse into just one item when the content list scrolls down, and expand into five items when the content list scrolls to the top.

If anyone has seen Airbnb's app, they do it really well.

I have been working on something, but, I am not a Javascript expert, so I have been struggling.

Does anyone know any examples that I can refer to?

[image]

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-custom-expandable-header-component-for-ionic-2/ Hope this wil help

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I need.

Comment: Cool . You are welcome ;)